# rack-rewrite with Rails 3.2.3 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rack, middleware, rack-middleware

I'm trying to set up rack-rewrite for a Rails 3.2.3 on Heroku cedar stack and everywhere I look it says to add something like:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  # rewrite rules
end
```

But trying to run this on Heroku gives me the error:

```
`assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: Rack::Lock (RuntimeError)
```

and indeed running "heroku rake middleware"
doesn't show Rack::Lock on the list while in development Rack::Lock is there.

First question is why Rack::Lock is not present on Heroku, is that correct?
Second question, if not before Rack::Lock, where should I insert Rack::Rewrite?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have threadsafe! enabled in your production environment config?

Comment: Yep, I do. Is that why Rack::Lock is not there in production?

Comment: yep! no mutex/locking in threadsafe!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use threadsafe! enabled in production, there is no Rack::Lock... so instead:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  #your coolness here
end
```

Comment: Do you mean?

`config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do`

I'll check it out.